# How do I compile Typescript source files into same directory, recursively, using a Gulp task?

Tags: recursion, typescript, compilation, gulp

I need to compile new .ts files into the same source directory recursively for each.

They're all sitting in different folders because I'm converting a project to use TypeScript.

I'm using a Gulp Task right now to try figure it out myself however I'd much appreciate it if someone has already worked out how to do it.

My code looks something like this

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(ts({
      target:         'ES6',
      outDir:         'Directory'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

I figured it out...
Solution:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*')
  .pipe(ts({
    outDir:     'directory',
    target:     'es6',
    pretty:     true,
    listFiles:  true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "recursively for each"? You are trying to just move .ts files to a new location or do you have .ts files you want to compile to .js and have those js files all be in a new location?

Comment: What I was trying to do was compile a ts file into a js file inside of the same directory as the original ts file. Eg: "c:/project/myClass.ts" INTO "c:/project/myClass.js"